# Detection of contamination from salicylic acid via either single excitation fluorometer or via absorbance

Tags: optical-properties, absorption, fluorescence, emission

My colleague detected fluorescent contamination likely from salicylic acid in some water samples. I have made a new batch and want to check whether my new samples also have this contamination.

**1**. Can I use a single excitation/emissions fluorometer to detect the presence of contamination from salicylic acid or a compound that fluoresces at the same wavelength as this. If so, what wavelength of emissions and excitation would be suitable?

**2.** Can I determine the presence of salicylic acid in my samples by measuring absorbance, if so, at what wavelength should I measure?

Comment: Not possible to assign "a random" fluorescence due to salicylic acid in an unlikely sample- seawater. There are millions of other natural and unnatural compounds which can fluoresce under UV. Point # 1: Not possible, 2. Again not possible. You first need to ensure your compound is salicylic acid from seawater from an another detector like mass spectrometer.

Comment: Also consider that a single molecule's fluorescence can be detected, but absorbance requires many to absorb a detectable amount.

Comment: (1) No, you will really need to measure the spectrum to be certain what is present. (2) fluorescence is a zero background technique so is orders of magnitude more sensitive that absorption which is a difference measurement. You can easily find the fluoresce and absorption spectra online.